# Accessing outer class from inner class without explicitly passing an instance

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes

The following code produces the output

```
outer::inner::inner, o=00000000
outer
outer::inner::val, o=00000000
outer::print
```

Can anyone explain how I can access the outer class method `print` through `o` without explicitly assigning `o`'s value at construction?

**Here `o` is null, but I can still invoke its methods.**

**I have tested this with MSVC 2017 and g++ 7.4.0 and the output is same.**

```
#include <iostream>

class outer {
public:
    outer() { 
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; 
    }

    class inner {
        outer *o = nullptr;
    public:
        inner() { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ", o=" << o << std::endl;
        }
        void val() { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ", o=" << o << std::endl;
            o->print(); // **call outer class method**
        }
    };

    inner i;

    void print() { 
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    outer o;
    o.i.val();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inner classes in C++ differentiate in scope only. Technically, at the assembly level, they are not part of the outer class.  Therefore you need an instance of the outer object as it if were any  other object, inner or whatever.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis What's confusing is that `o` is null, but I can still invoke its methods. I'm not sure if I have explained the question well.

Comment: It's called "undefined behavior". With your C++ compiler it seems to work. Someone else's compiler might produce code that crashes. Another compiler might produce code that causes demons to fly out of everyone's noses. That's what "undefined behavior" means. The C++ standard does not define any particular result here, hence "undefined behavior". Welcome to C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I edited the question to mention the compilers I have tested this with, and the behavior is same.

Comment: And my comment also remains the same. You cannot expect any defined behavior from the shown code. Full stop. Even the same code, compiled just once by the compiler, might work Tuesdays, but on Sundays everyone has to deal with demons flying out of their nose every time they run this code. This is still undefined behavior, no matter how many compilers you try.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. Do you suggest I should not trust the compiler? Is it a bug in the compiler? I cannot explain this behavior, and I came across this by accident.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour permits the compiler to generate code that works, or code that appears to work, or sometimes works but occasionally sets fire to your keyboard. The behaviour is _not defined_, so expecting some specific defined behaviour suggests you don't understand something. The compiler is not required to tell your your code has UB, you're required to write correct code in the first place.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): the first [external link](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) is well worth the read.

Comment: I suggest that you do not write code that does this. It is not the compiler's job to make sure that your code is correct. Just because some C++ source compiles, doesn't mean that it is correct and will work right. C++, nor any other programming language, guarantees that. It is your responsibility, as a programmer, to write code that has well-defined, and correct results. The shown code does not have defined results. It is not your compiler's job to tell you this. It is your job to understand this.

Comment: As a note, the primary reason that calling `static_cast<outer*>(nullptr)->print()` here isn't causing a crash is that you aren't actually using the function's `this` pointer and/or accessing anything through it.  You're effectively tapdancing along the one safe path in a landshark-infested minefield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your example to

```
struct S
{
    void f() { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    S* s = nullptr;
    s->f();
}
```

And **dereferencing `nullptr` is UB.** So anything can happen.

Why does it **appear** to work?

Because, in practice, method functions are generally implemented as if there were regular functions with extra parameter:

`void S::f()` -> `void f(S*)` (or `void f(S&)`)

and so, code becomes:

```
void f(S* /*unused*/) { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }

int main()
{
    S* unused = nullptr;
    f(unused);
}
```

In that case, compiler transforms UB in valid code, as `unused` is not used, it doesn't crash and does what you expect.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments and the answer. I very well understand it is unsafe code, but wonder how it works without a crash.

Comment: @dhanushka: you would probably have a crash if you use a data member in `f`